# Trying to understand what are namespaces in Java

Tags: java, namespaces

I am working on a java -  rest api project. I am confused what a name space is ? is it same as a class or is it related to memory used?

Comment: Have you already checked out the [Wikipedia article on Namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A package is a named collection of classes (and possibly subpackages). Packages serve to group related classes and define a namespace for the classes they contain. The Java platform includes packages with names that begin with java, javax and etc.